# Skype crashes saying problem with audio capture

Tags: 13.04, skype, ubuntu-gnome

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E430.

I have installed ubuntu gnome on it.

I installed Skype 4.2.0.11 and it has never worked for me.

Calling echo/sound testing service crashes saying problem with audio capture.

Does anyone have a clue as to how to fix this

PS: I have never installed any sound related driver or software.

Comment: are you on 32 or 64bit system and how did you install

Comment: My laptop 64bit system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Skype by downloading from skype.com and had a similar issue.  My Skype would not crash, but it would fail to make a call, saying "Problem with Audio Capture".  The solution for me was to libpulse0:i386, which can be done from the terminal like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

Comment: I had given up on skype and was using google voice only till now. Thanks for the fix. It works

Comment: This does not work for me.